# Why won't GFCIs indicator light show on plug?

Tags: electrical, gfci

My handyman installed 10 new Gfci's in a 1987 home.  There has never been any in the home.  They all work when you plug something in and do not trip- but the the indicator lights will not come on any of the plugs.  What is wrong?

Comment: What indicator lights? On the GFI receptacles themselves? Or on the cord plugs?

Comment: If you're taking about the little light on the GFCI receptacle itself, those are only always on on some make/model GFCIs. Some make/models only power the light when the GFCI trips.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tester101 said, not all GFCI's have lights that display in the normal (as opposed to the tripped) state.

If the test and reset buttons work as expected, you're probably fine.

If you want to be absolutely sure, get a GFCI tester (US$5 or so). If the tester's lights say you're hooked up correctly, and tapping its button trips the GFCI, you're fine.